# Choosing the right deep learning model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm facing a real-time problem which has 4 features:
`Vmean`, `Vmedian`, `Vnow`, `VV`.
What I'm trying to do is:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
     model.fit(X[i], X[i+1])
     model.predict(X[i+1])
```

That is, I'm trying to predict the value of `X[i+2]` through `X[i+1]` and `X[i]`, because one row is related with the next one and so on.
This is my model:

```
def kerasModel():
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4, 1), name='input_shape')
    x = keras.layers.LSTM(100, name='lstm_0')(input_layer)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='lstm_dropout')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(64, name='x2')(x)
    output = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='linear', name='x3')(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
    
    adam = keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.005)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
    
    return model
```

But it is not working. It's not predicting next value as it should be doing. My question is: is there any paper or rules to make a good deep learning model based on your features? Plus, based in this problem, which could be a good model?

Comment: You’re trying to fit and predict a new model each time and that is a major issue. Each model has nothing to “learn” except one data point. In modeling, you train a model based on a part of the dataset (training set) and evaluate it on another, unseen part of the same dataset. Then you predict on new data going forward with the confidence your model is sound. Your problem is not the model, but how to model in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My rule is to make baseline, then try to improve model, clean or grub more data, playing with training process etc. In your case baseline may be simpler time-series [multi-step dense model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-step_dense).

[image: trainable model]

Answer (score 4):

> My question is: is there any paper or rules to make a good deep
> learning model based on your features?

To my knowledge there is no such "Rule book" that's going to tell you what kind of model to use in any situation.
Deep Learning papers tend to focus on specific application (picture classification, segmentation, machine translation,...) and within this sub-field you'll find specialized architecture that tends to perform better for specific tasks.

> Plus, based in this problem,
> which could be a good model?

It's just not possible to answer this question without knowing your problem and data in detail etc...

On thing that's worth pondering though is what "good" means. If you look at the marginal performance improvement of Deep Learning model over time on a dataset like MNIST you'll see that even "baseline" MLP can get acceptable error rate compared to more advanced and specialized architecture.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database

So, before jumping to more advanced architecture I always start with a small and simple model to get the code to work then I gradually increase complexity as long as it yields a marginal improvement in the metrics worth the time.

> But it is not working

**First** :

as @emremrah said, your OP is not specific enough, but looking at your code I think the first problem comes from you using a function instead of sub-classing `Keras Model` to define you model. Since you are calling the model inside a for loop each call to the function would yield a new model instead of fitting the existing model.

Try sub-classing the model and create an instance as in this example :

```
class Dense_Detector(Model):
  def __init__(self, flight_len, param_len):
    super(Dense_Detector, self).__init__()
    self.input_dim = (flight_len, param_len)
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(8, activation="relu")
      ])
    
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
      layers.Dense(flight_len * param_len, activation="relu"),
      layers.Reshape(self.input_dim)
      ])
    
  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded


model = Dense_Detector(flight_len, param_len, hidden_state=16)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=1.0)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())
```

**Second**

Unless you have some specific reason to do so, I would not mix training and prediction in the same loop as it does not make sense.

The goal of training is for your model to adjust its internal state to build an "understanding" of the task your are trying to achieve, in this case predicting the next step, by exposing it to a series of examples `(data, label)`. In the hope that after seeing hundred or thousands of the it will be able to correctly classify unseen data.

What you are doing is training the model on one instance :

```
model.fit(X[i], X[i+1])
```

and then trying to predict the next one :

```
model.predict(X[i+1])
```

So basically you are expecting the model to have built an understanding of your data after seeing one instance only.

I won't give you a "plug & play" solution unfortunately, but I hope this will help you gain a better understanding of your model and what your are doing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any paper or rules to make a good deep
> learning model based on your features?

As @yoan-b-m-sc already mentioned, there is no rule book for model selection (and more importantly hyper-parameter selection). It's mostly intuition and a lot of trial and error.

But you can get some hints based on the question at hand. For example

- If your input features have some kind of a local correlation (like in image, video, audio, etc.), you probably should use Convolutional layers.
- If your input features have variable length (like in natural language processing, audio processing, etc.), you probably should use RNNs.
- If your input features don't have a temporal or spatial correlation with each other, you probably should use a normal Multi-layer non-linear Neural Network.

These are hints, and the final solution as mentioned before comes from intuition and trial and error.

If you're asking "But how am I suppose to get that intuition?" my suggestion is to start by learning why different architectures have been created. For example, start by learning why RNNs have been invented in the first place. Or by learning what kind of problem does CNNs try to solve and why they're working?

Jeff Hinton's "Neural Network For Machine Learning" and Andrew Ng's "Machine Learning" courses are a good starting point.

> based on this problem, which could be a good model?

If you're sure that X[i-1] and X[i-2] have enough information to predict X[i], I suggest ditching the LSTM and use a simple feed-forward neural network (a bunch of dense layers).

Even if you know that the last 'k' elements are not sufficient for a perfect prediction, but can create a good estimation, try a simple neural network on them first before trying LSTMs. RNNs are more complex and require more tweaking.

Finally, keep in mind that a "bad choice of model" is not the only reason why you're model is not working. The reason could be lack of sufficient examples, bad initialization, wrong normalization on the inputs and outputs, etc.